# iOS - Simple Facebook Authentication

Tags: ios, facebook, oauth, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to authenticate my user on FB with my app in a simple manner, the iOS SDK has this SSO explanation and that's pretty much it, and it seems a bit extreme since I pretty much have to wrap up my entire app in FB goodness, at least that's what they guide you through.

Is there just a simple way, be it with the SDK or some other manner, to guide the user through the OAuth process and retrieve the access token and user data, like name, email and birthdate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One shortcut here is using something like [Parse](https://parse.com/) to handle it for you. They actually also include a very nicely made login view controller that does exactly what you're looking for. You can see it [here](http://blog.parse.com/2012/04/23/a-beautiful-log-in-screen-for-your-mobile-app/).

Comment: Seems to work with the iOS SDK as well as far as I can see, and it's a bit of overkill for what I want, I just want to obtain the user access token and user data, don't want my user to sign in with FB.

Comment: Thanks Dima, seeing that made me dig a little deeper into how I can manage to do this without all the FB intrusion, I'll update my question later with the code.